# In "The Impossible Astronaut", why do we see an event that was later erased from history?

Tags: doctor-who

In Eleventh Doctor episode *The Impossible Astronaut*, why do we see

> River shooting the Teselecta

and not

> the moment when River chose not to kill the Doctor, and instead created the alternate universe.

Is this just for suspense in the story, or is there a logical explanation?

Answer (score 5):

> There was no alternate timeline created in The Impossible Astronaut. She did shoot the Teselecta. The Doctor told her it was OK, that it had to be done. All that happened was that she hesitated.

Comment: But later we see river choosing not to shoot the doctor..does it mean that it never happened?

Comment: It happened on an aborted timeline.  You can argue endlessly about whether an aborted timeline ever "happened".

Comment: River at first refused to shoot the Teselecta, and that caused time to splinter. In the resultant alternate timeline, the Doctor convinced River to shoot the Teselecta. Time then reverted and River shot the Teselecta. So that was now what always happened since River never shooting it was overwritten.

Comment: It does make sense!Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

**Because that's what, in the end, actually happened.**

After all's said and done, and the alternative "universe comes to an end" scenario timelines have been discarded, what actually happened at Lake Silencio is that

> River shot the Teselecta in the form of the Doctor.

It would have made no sense to show in "The Impossible Astronaut" that she didn't, because:

1. that would have led to the whole "The Wedding of River Song" timeline, which never actually happened - "The Impossible Astronaut" shows the real/actual chain of events;
2. it would have totally derailed the story to go into that timeline at this point, as well as not showing all the events of the rest of Series 6 which happened 'after' (in some sense) Lake Silencio and often as a direct consequence of what Amy and Rory saw there (such as making the Doctor find Canton).

TL;DR: why would they show a failed aborted timeline rather than the event which led on to the rest of the series happening as it did?

**Alternatively, time is in flux and there could be more than one timeline involved here.**

We don't know exactly how [fixed points in time](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Fixed_point_in_time) work. Is it "fixed" that

> River kills the Teselecta with the Doctor inside,

or is it only "fixed" that

> she appears to kill the Doctor himself?

Perhaps the **original timeline** shown in "The Impossible Astronaut" was one where the Doctor really did die ... that led on to the rest of Series 6 and ultimately to him coming back to Lake Silencio where she *doesn't* kill him and creates the **failed timeline** where everything happens at once ... and *that* in turn led to him whispering the big reveal in her ear and her going ahead to shoot and creating the **third and final timeline** where she shoots the Teselecta instead of the real Doctor.

> [image: Explanatory diagram]

Comment: This would be greatly improved with a little diagram of the possibilities, I think!

Comment: @WebHead Done. And after all the time and effort put into that diagram, I better get that bounty :-P

Answer (score 0):

*The Wedding of River Song* doesn't take place in an alternate universe, exactly. It takes place in "one moment". When River refuses to act according to her "destiny", time ceases to flow. In between when River hesitates and she does it is one moment during which all of the events of *The Wedding of River Song* take place. While she and the audience see it as an extended period of time, for the outside observers, no time passes.